# GET Request in .NET Core 6 with multiple parameters in a query - using bitwise

Tags: c#, .net, get, bitwise-operators, react-fullstack

I'm trying to make it so I can send queries like: But I am having trouble using the bitwise functions to do so. The var orders is wrong because TypeEnum can't be used with IEnumerable

Answer (score 1):

I think you're doing more work than necessary. [`Enum.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse?view=net-7.0#system-enum-tryparse(system-type-system-string-system-object@)) is able to take a comma separated list of names and parse it into the correct value:

```
public static void Get(string orderTypes)
{
    var orders = Enumerable.Empty<OrderList>();
    if (Enum.TryParse(typeof(TypeEnum), orderTypes, out var enumOrderTypes))
    {
        orders = _context.OrderLists.Where(o => (o.orderType & enumOrderTypes) > 0);
    }
    return Ok(orders);
}
```

However, this assumes that `orderTypes` only contains valid enum value names. So if `orderTypes` was `"Standard,IDontExist"` `Enum.TryParse` would return false.

---

If you want to allow invalid names and just filter them out, you can do it like so:

```
public static void Get(string orderTypes)
{
    var typeList = orderTypes.Split(',',
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries | StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries);

    // I'd recommend adding 'None = 0' as a default value for the enum
    TypeEnum enumOrderTypes = TypeEnum.None;
    foreach (var strType in typeList)
    {
        if (Enum.TryParse(typeof(TypeEnum), strType, out var enumType))
        {
            enumOrderTypes |= (TypeEnum)enumType;
        }
    }
    
    var orders = _context.OrderLists.Where(o => (o.orderType & enumOrderTypes) > 0);
    
    return Ok(orders);
}
```

In this example if `orderTypes` was `"Standard,IDontExist"`, then `enumOrderTypes` would end up just containing `Standard`.

Check out [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ojHzQh) for a demonstration.